# Cannot type into some text fields during installation

Tags: system-installation, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 in a VM (Hyper-V), however I cannot get past the "Who are you?" screen. I can't type anything into the fields name, computer name or user name. However, I *can* type in the password fields, and <kbd>Tab</kbd> also works. I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to another console and type there, too.

My theory is that the keyboard works in the VM per se, but there is some problem with the installation application. Maybe a modifier key is stuck. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, but the problem has gone after having resetting (Ctrl+R) the virtual machine.